# Computation of generalized least squares solutions of large sparse systems

Tags: computational-statistics, sparse, generalized-least-squares

Suppose $X$ and $\Omega$ are large sparse matrices, with $\Omega$ symmetric positive definite (but not diagonal), and $y$ is a vector.

I want to find the generalized least squares solution:

$$\hat\beta:=\arg\min_{\beta}{(y-X\beta)^\top\Omega^{-1}(y-X\beta)}$$

In my context, $\Omega^{-1}$ is sparse and easy to find, as are the Cholesky factors $\Lambda$ of $\Omega=\Lambda \Lambda^\top$.

(In fact, in my context $\Omega = I \otimes \tilde\Omega$ for some $\tilde\Omega$.)

However, it appears that $\Lambda^{-1} X$ is dense, thus it is infeasible to transform this problem into a standard least squares problem and then use the "LSQR" algorithm for example.

Is there an algorithm for handling problems of this form?

Comment: Just to help fix the problem size, very roughly how large is "large"?

Comment: X is about 500000 x 6000.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a comment but with too long

Consider that you can probably do

$$(y - X\beta)^\top(I_N \otimes \tilde \Omega^{-1})(y-X\beta) = \sum_i^{N} (y_i - X_i\beta)^\top \tilde \Omega^{-1}(y_i - X_i\beta)$$

then factor $\tilde \Omega^{-1} = \Lambda \Lambda^{\top}$

then you can calculate $\sum_i^{N} (y_i - X_i\beta)^\top \tilde \Omega^{-1}(y_i - X_i\beta)$ as the sum of squares from a regression on transformed data

$$\Lambda^\top y_i = \Lambda^\top X_i \beta + \Lambda^\top \epsilon_i$$

denote residuals from this regression as $\hat e$ then

$$\hat e_i^\top \hat e_i = (\Lambda^\top(y_i - X_i\hat \beta))^\top(\Lambda^\top(y_i - X_i\hat \beta)) = (y_i - X_i\hat \beta)^\top\Lambda\Lambda^\top(y_i-X_i\hat \beta)$$

so premultiply per group of observations instead for the entire system.

Comment: Thanks. Exploiting the kronecker structure does help a little, but it still seems impractically slow. Forming $X^\top\Omega^{-1}X$ is taking around 300 seconds. Since this is part of a nested optimisation, this is a killer.